# PHP Regex missing two matches

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I almost have my regular expression down for skimming html pages, but have ran into two issues that I am trying to get squished before I an proceed, I need to be able to match both empty and slash (and empty closing quote) but have exhausted my ability to see what I'm doing, could someone help me with the final bit?

```
$pathspec='in-front';

$subjects = array(
    '<base href="http://foo.com/images/" target="_blank">', # no changes              (correct)
    '<base href="/" target="_blank">',                      # '/in-front/'            (fails)
    '<a href="https://foo.com/images/">Foo</a>',            # no changes              (correct)
    '<a href="">Foo</a>',                                   # '/in-front/'            (fails)
    '<img src="bar/foo.png" />',                            # no changes              (correct)
    '<img src="/bar/foo.png" />',                           # '/in-front/bar/foo.png' (correct)
);


foreach ($subjects AS $subject)

    echo preg_replace( '/(href|src)=["\']?\/(?!\/)([^"\'>]+)["\']?/', "$1='/$pathspec/$2'", $subject ) . "\n";

die;
```

Expected output is in the comments portion, Thank you.

Comment: @php_nub_qq: Huh what?

Comment: So basically what you want is to add `$pathspec` to any empty or root href attribute, yes?

Comment: @php_nub_qq close, read the regex carefully, and also the expected outputs along with their inputs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this pattern:

```
$pattern = '~\b(?:href|src)\s*=\s*(["\']?+)\K(?:/|(?=[\s>]|\1))~i';
$replacement = "/$pathspec/";

$result = preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $subject);
```

Comment: This pattern does not correctly avoid protocols, and matches everything: http://pastebin.com/Sfm4004w it also needs an escape in `(["']?)`

Comment: @ehime: sorry, i have forgotten the `+`.

Comment: Great late answer, I've already accepted but plus one for it, works great

Comment: @CasmirEtHippolyte something that I had noticed about yours that does not work is if it encounters something like this in javascript `ga.src = ('' == document.location.protocol` since this does not do a look behind for a whitespace, it will replace it =(

Comment: @ehime: you can skip the javascript content by adding at the begining of the pattern: `<script\b(?>[^<]++|<(?!/script))*</script>(*SKIP)(?!)|`

Comment: @CasmirEtHippolyte for some reason `~<script\b(?>[^<]++|<(?!/script))*</script>(*SKIP)(?!)|\b(?:href|src)\s*=\s*(["\']?+)\K(?:/(?!/)|(?=[\s>]|\1))~i` isn't working

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43354/discussion-between-ehime-and-casimir-et-hippolyte)

Comment: @ehime: ok, look at this: http://pastebin.com/PdMsq0qL . I have seen your code but not tested it, however note: preg_replace can deal with pattern/replacement arrays, using array_values and a for loop is useless. no need to escape the slash here `<\/script>` since the delimiter is `~`

Comment: @CasmirEtHippolyte due to thefact that I want to rewrite urls and not encapsulated code, the solution I came up with was: `~(?<!\.)\b(?:href|src)\s*=\s*(["\']?+)\K(?:/(?!/)|(?=[\s>]|\1))~i` which will do a look behind for a leading dot and disregard. Good point about looping, I thought only str_replace could handle arrays, removing...

Answer (score 2):

See if this works for you

```
preg_replace('#(href|src)=["\'](?:/|/(?!\/)(\S+?)|)["\']#',"$1='/$pathspec/$2'",$subject)
```

Comment: FWIW, I thiknk the original regex avoided matching // within the quotes whereas this one accepts it.

Comment: @PeterAlfvin I edited his answer to avoid protocol relative URLS, waiting for him to accept the change

Comment: The pattern will only match empty urls or urls starting with a forward slash, how could a double-slash cause an interference?

Comment: Double slashes are considered 'Protocol relative urls' aka `//google.com` will be protocol free for either `https://google.com` or `http://google.com` whether the passing host issuing with SSL certification or not. http://goo.gl/ENNhQF Something to keep in mind when handling _other_ peoples data ;)

Comment: @ehime that's something I wasn't aware of. Could you suggest the edit again because I automatically assumed it was related to the `uknown modifier` error and rejected it without even reading.